# ArrayListModel will not sync with JList

Tags: model-view-controller, jlist

I have combed through SO, and have found many questions on the topic of my problem but do not answer it.
I am setting up an MVC, I have set up things correctly to best of my knowledge but I cannot get the Controller to show in my view. I am working on an assignment that essentially is a program for a Video Rental Store.

First, In a class called RentalStoreGUI, I set up my panels and everything looks good when I run.

```
RentalStoreEngine model = new RentalStoreEngine();
    JList<DVD> list = new JList<DVD>();
    list.setModel(model);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    list.setVisible(true);

    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);



    add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

As you can see I set my model for the list based on another class called RentalStoreEngine() and it implements AbstractListModel. The Abstract List model is functioning when I do class specific testing and all of the necessary methods are implemented. Here is an example of my add method from that class:

```
public  void add(DVD d){
    if (d != null){
        rentals.add(d);//rentals is an arrayList<DVD> instantiated earlier
        fireIntervalAdded(this, rentals.size() - 1, rentals.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the actionPerformed method, it runs DVD_Dialog which simply gets some input from the user and creates a new DVD object from that.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == rentDVD){

        DVD_Dialog = new RentDVDDialog(this, null);
        DVD_Dialog.clear();
        DVD_Dialog.setVisible(true);
        dvd = new DVD(DVD_Dialog.getTitleText(),DVD_Dialog.getRenterText(),
                DVD_Dialog.getRentedOnText(), DVD_Dialog.getDueBackText());

        if(DVD_Dialog.closeStatus() == true){
        model.add(dvd); 

        }
    }
```

Eclipse gives me no errors, until I run it. I then receive a nullPointerException at the line model.add(dvd); Based on all my research the list.setModel(model) and the fireIntervalAdded method line should update the Jlist on its own. But it does not. And as I said, class specific testing for both the GUI and the Model are producing the desired results, but when it comes to integrating them I am at a loss.

Comment: please post the stacktrace of the NullPointerException.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Package1.RentalStoreGUI.actionPerformed(RentalStoreGUI.java:124)

Then there is all of the actionPerformed exceptions that occur as a result

Comment: Your problem is in RentalStoreGUI.javaat line 124. You're referencing a variable which is null.

Comment: I know, I stated that in my last paragraph. I cannot find any such reason its throwing this exception. None of my individual fields are returning null when I debug. I thought maybe someone might see the error

Comment: Your model field seems to be null at that time. Maybe add some System.out lines...

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did some more Println lines in the model class, and found I forgot to code this.ArrayList = ArrayList. Thanks again!